# Have a User input a date and it will search through the worksheet to add an orange line

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to create a macro where it will prompt a user to enter a date and it will take that value and compare it to each date value in Column E.

It has already been presorted by date. I am just looking to have the macro insert One Orange line from Columns A-L after it finds the the last value where the row above it has an earlier date, and the row below it either has the same date or a date further out.

The file will vary from a few dozen lines to 2000+ and includes spaces in between rows.

I am working on my skillset for each component of the code but am having trouble piecing it all together.

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub datechecker()


Dim ddate As Date
Dim rCell As Range
Dim r As Long
    If IsDate(Range("B:B")) Then
        ddate = Application.InputBox(MsgGP, TitleMsg, FormatDateTime(Date, vbShortDate), Type:=1)
    Else
        MsgBox "Non valid date"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each rCell In .Range(.Cells(1, "E"), .Cells(.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp))
         If IsDate(rCell) Then
            If rCell >= ddate Or rCell.Value = "" Then
               rCell.Offset (-1)
                
                Else
                If ddate >= rCell Then
                rCell.Row.Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
                
            End If
         End If
      Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried using "Record Macro"?

Comment: Yes, that's how I came across the code to make the highlight. Unfortunately that's as far as I can go since each sheet and workbook has a different amount of lines and it can be troublesome just searching for it.

Looking to macro this so I can make it part of a bigger macro!

Thanks for your time.